# Application of Maximum Likelihood estimation (MLE) to the step of Feasible Generalized Least Square (FGLS)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

I have the following regression

$$y = X\beta +u$$

where $y$ and $u$ are $(n\times 1)$ and $X$ is a fixed $(n \times k)$ matrix with full column rank and $\beta$ is an unknown $(k\times 1)$ vector of parameters.

$E(u)=0$ and $var(u)=\sigma^2 V$ with $(n\times n) $ symmetric and positive definite non-diagonal matrix $V$.

Let $\hat {\beta_{OLS}}= (X'X)^{-1} X'y$

Suppose $$u_t =\phi u_{t-1} +v_t $$ where $v_t$ is a white noise process with variance $\sigma_v^2$ and $\phi$ is an unknown parameter with $|\phi|<1$.

Describe how to get the feasible generalized least square (FGLS) estimator for $\beta$.

In the FGLS estimation procedure, we should use the maximized likelihood estimator $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$, which should be obtained through the conditional log-likelihood  function set conditional on the first observation.

---

**What I did**

I obtain the variance-covariance matrix as follows:

[image]

Since $\phi$ is unknown, the matrix $V$ is also unknown. Therefore, we need to use FGLS as follows:

*Step 1:* Estimate the generalized regression $y=X\beta + u$ by OLS and obtain $\hat {u}$.

*Step 2:* Construct the auxiliary regression $\hat {u_t}= \phi \hat {u_{t-1}}+ v_t$ in order to obtain $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$ and $\hat {v_{MLE}}$.

For that, I write down a likelihood function

$$v_t \sim N(0, \sigma_v^2)$$

$\hat {u_t} \sim N(0, \sigma_v^2)$

$I(\theta, u)=- \frac{n}{2} log(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2} log(\sigma_v^2) - \frac{n}{2\sigma_v^2} (\hat {u_t}- \phi \hat {u_{t-1}})'(\hat {u_t} - \phi \hat {u_{t-1}}) $

where $\theta = [\phi \sigma_v^2]$

FOC:

$$\frac{\partial I(\theta, u)}{\partial \phi} = 0$$

$$\hat {\phi_{MLE}} = (\hat {u_{t-1}}' \hat {u_{t-1}})\hat {u_{t-1}}' \hat {u_{t}}$$

**Step 3:**

By using $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$ and $\hat {v_{MLE}}$, I will obtain the matrix $V$ and calculate $\hat {\beta_{FGLS}} = (X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}y$

---

I couldn’t do the step 2. The question states the conditional log-likelihood function, however I cannot write down this log-likelihood function as conditional function to solve for $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$ and $\hat {v_{MLE}}$.

Please help me how to calculate the step 2. Thank you for your all kinds of helps and suggestions.

Comment: Hi: Check out Andrew Harvey's "Econometric Analysis of Time Series". This book has beautiful, step by step explanations for  how to construct MLE's for that type of problem.

Comment: I have no chance to get this book. How can I find this book? Or can you share the related part of the book as an answer? I really need to learn how to solve for this question. Can you help me to solve this question? Thank you for your helps @mlofton

Comment: I can send the relevant section to you through email but let me first see if I can find a pdf of the book on the internet. I bought it on amazon but Harvey's books are generally expensive. The title is "The Econometric Analysis of Time Series" by Andrew Harvey. Let me see if I can find it somewhere and get back to you.

Comment: Hi: You can buy it for 3 dollars from Abe books. It says that condition is poor but who cares really.  https://www.abebooks.com/Econometric-Analysis-Time-Series-Harvey-A/31260498349/bd?cm_mmc=msn-_-comus_shopp_textbook-_-naa-_-naa&msclkid=3d436d9c8eda1f4da91a0eb402d17799 Still let me see if I can find a pdf of the book on the net.

Comment: This is not Harvey's but Pollock pretty much explains the same thing. https://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/ELOMET/LECTURE5.PDF.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no closed form MLE for this problem. People have been analyzing this problem since the 50's and the most common approach is two stage Cochrane Orcutt ( see Pollock's file for a full description ) the results of which can be viewed as a "pseudo" MLE. Note that you can't do what you're doing in Step 2 because you don't have the $\hat{u_t}$ values. Therefore, an iterative scheme is the only feasible approach.

Comment: Note that GLS is an estimation technique (thus in the same category as maximum likelihood), not a model.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you. I corrected the title.

Comment: Though it seems I was able to understand and answer your question, your mathematical expressions and $\LaTeX$ code would benefit from some clean-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\hat{u}_t = \phi \hat{u}_{t-1} + v_t,\, v_t \sim \mathcal N\left(0, \sigma^2_{v}\right)$ implies $\hat{u}_t | \hat{u}_{t-1}\sim \mathcal N\left(\phi \hat{u}_{t-1}, \sigma^2_{v}\right)$ for $t = 2, \ldots, n$.
With the additional assumption $\hat{u}_1 \sim  \mathcal N\left(0, \sigma^2_{v}/\left(1 - \phi^2\right)\right)$ you get the full log-likelihood kernel
$$
l\left(\phi,\sigma^2_v;\hat{u}\right) = -\frac{n}{2} \cdot \ln\left(\sigma^2_v\right) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln\left(1-\phi^2\right) -
\frac{1}{2\sigma^2_v} \left[\sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\phi\hat{u}_{t-1}\right)^2 + \left(1 - \phi^2\right)\hat{u}_1^2 \right].
$$
There is no closed-form solution for the maximum likelihood estimates $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2_v$ in this case, but they can be determined iteratively.

Alternatively, you could treat $\hat{u}_1$ as deterministic/known and just maximize the conditional likelihood by maximizing the conditional log-likelihood kernel
$$
l_c\left(\phi,\sigma^2_v;\hat{u}\right) = -\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot \ln\left(\sigma^2_v\right) -
\frac{1}{2\sigma^2_v} \sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\phi\hat{u}_{t-1}\right)^2. 
$$
The corresponding score equations
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial l_c}{\partial \phi}\left(\phi,\sigma^2_v;\hat{u}\right) =
\frac{1}{\sigma^2_v} \sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\phi\hat{u}_{t-1}\right) \cdot \hat{u}_{t-1} \overset{!}{=} 0 \\
\iff \sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\phi\hat{u}_{t-1}\right) \cdot \hat{u}_{t-1} = 0
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial l_c}{\partial \sigma^2_v}\left(\phi,\sigma^2_v;\hat{u}\right) =
-\frac{n-1}{2\sigma^2_v} + 
\frac{1}{2\left(\sigma^2_v\right)^2} \sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\phi\hat{u}_{t-1}\right)^2 \overset{!}{=} 0 \\
\iff -\left(n - 1\right) + 
\frac{1}{\sigma^2_v} \sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\phi\hat{u}_{t-1}\right)^2  = 0
\end{align}
$$
then yield the maximum conditional likelihood estimates
$$
\begin{align}
&\hat{\phi} = \frac{\sum_{t=2}^n\hat{u}_t\hat{u}_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^n\hat{u}_{t-1}^2}, \\
&\hat{\sigma}^2_v = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{t=2}^n\left(\hat{u}_t-\hat{\phi}\hat{u}_{t-1}\right)^2, 
\end{align}
$$
from which you only need $\hat{\phi}$ to calculate $\hat{\beta}_\text{FGLS}$ since the matrix $V$ does not depend on $\sigma^2_v$.

---

Instead of the two-step FGLS procedure you could also use a (full) maximum likelihood approach with the original data that, under the assumption of a multivariate normal $u$, computes $\left(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\sigma}^2, \hat{\phi}\right)$ as maximizer of the likelihood
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\beta, \sigma^2, \phi; y, X\right) = \left(2\pi\sigma^2\right)^{-n/2}|V|^{-1/2} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(y-X\beta\right)^\top V^{-1} \left(y-X\beta\right)\right),
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
&V = \frac{1}{1-\phi^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \phi & \phi^2 & \cdots & \phi^{n-1}\\
\phi & 1 & \phi & \cdots & \phi^{n-2}\\
\phi^2 & \phi & 1 & \cdots & \phi^{n-3}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\
\phi^{n-1} & \phi^{n-2} & \phi^{n-3}& \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix},|V|=\left(1-\phi^2\right)^{-1},\\
&V^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\phi & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
-\phi & 1+\phi^2 & -\phi & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\phi & 1+\phi^2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1+\phi^2 & -\phi\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -\phi & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$
Usually, this would be done by iteratively computing the maximizer of the log-likelihood kernel
$$
l\left(\beta, \sigma^2, \phi; y, X\right) = -\frac{n}{2} \cdot \ln\left(\sigma^2\right) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln\left(1-\phi^2\right) -
\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(y-X\beta\right)^\top V^{-1} \left(y-X\beta\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @1190 You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @statmerkur: very nice answer but, in your second approach, where do the $\hat{u_t}$ come from ? also, in your third approach, would you be using some non-linear optimization method like BFGS or something like that ? Thanks. Oh,  basically, what I'm saying is that that I don't think there is a closed form MLE for the OP's problem ? Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton The $\hat{u}_t$'s are the OLS residuals resulting from regressing $y$ on $X$. Yes, there is no closed-form MLE in the third approach$-$that's why I wrote "iteratively". I would go for a Newton-Raphson or quasi-Newton (e.g. BFGS) type of optimization algorithm.

Comment: @statmerkur In the closed-form MLE in the third approach, only a 1D search over $\phi$ needs to be performed, as I describe in my answer, because to each specific value of $\phi$ corresponds a specific matrix $V_\phi$ and the intermediate solution for $\beta_{\phi}$ has an optimal closed-form GLS solution, i.e., for each specific value of $\phi$ we are maximizing the likelihood.

Comment: @Number The (log-)likelihood depends on the parameters $\beta, \phi,$ and $\sigma^2$ in such a way that the solutions to the corresponding score equations are interdependent. Unfortunately, I don't see how the "1D search over $\phi$" that you propose can work here.

Comment: @statmerkur I completely agree that the likelihood is interdependent on the parameters, but for each $\phi$ the GLS maximizes the conditional likelihood for that $\phi$. This is a case of the Rao-Blackwell theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem). Therefore, the iteration always converges towards a local maximum, which I assume is global in this case (as Newton-Raphson would to a local one). This method is very similar (but not the same as) the Expectation-Maximization procedure, which iteratively improves a lower bound for the maximum likelihood.

Comment: Okay. But in the second approach, if you are regressing Y on X first to get the $\hat{u}_t$, then it sounds like 2 Stage Cochrane-Orcutt but with just one iteration ? Should it not be iterative also in that one should go back and forth between the OLS regression and the $\hat{u}_t$ until the $\hat{u}_t$ residuals don't change any more ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @Number Without $\sigma^2$ you can't evaluate the (log-)likelihood. Do you want to fix $\sigma^2$ to some value in the optimization or modify the (log-)likelihood function? I'm positive that we could maximize the [profile (log-)likelihood](https://web.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/chapter3.pdf) of $\phi$ (treating both $\beta$ *and* $\sigma^2$, whose MLEs have closed-form expressions for a fixed $\phi$,  as nuisance parameters) in a one dimensional optimization. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @mlofton You can iterate the steps (by inserting the current $\hat{\phi}$ into $V$ to obtain a new $\hat{V}$, recalculating the new residuals based on the new $\hat{\beta}_\text{FGLS} = \left(X^\top\hat{V}^{-1}X\right)^{-1}X^\top\hat{V}^{-1}y$, and a new $\hat{\phi}$ based on these). However, as long as we have a consistent estimator of $V$, $\hat{\beta}_\text{FGLS}$ is (under general regularity conditions) asymptotically efficient *at every iteration*, so you don't really gain anything by using more iterations.

Comment: @statmerkur: I read Harvey's text more carefully and your procedure is actually not Cochrane-Orcutt but they do state it as a possible procedure for obtaining $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$. He doesn't refer to it an MLE procedure ( the $\hat{u_t}$ are not resulting from a likelihood approach but rather from a regression framework. Two step Cochrane Orcutt iterated is referred to as MLE procedure )  but he does say that it's consistent. Thanks for interesting procedure. I understand it now finally.

Comment: @mlofton I'm not familiar with Harvey's book. But yes, usually $\hat{\phi} = \sum_{t=2}^n\hat{u}_t\hat{u}_{t-1}/\sum_{t=2}^n\hat{u}_{t-1}^2$ is described as the OLS estimate of $\phi$ when $\left(\hat{u}_{t}\right)_{t=2,\ldots,n}$ is regressed on $\left(\hat{u}_{t}\right)_{t=1,\ldots,n-1}$.

Comment: Dear @statmerkur I have another question on unit root test. If you are mind, can you please look at that as well? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589970/deriving-adf-unit-root-test-form-for-the-time-series-with-quadratic-deterministi

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that Feasible Generalized Least Square (FGLS) should be used when the covariance matrix of the errors $cov(u) = \sigma^2V$ has a completely unknown form. However, in this problem, you have very specific prior knowledge of its form: it's the autocorrelation matrix of a 1st order autoregressive process, AR(1), which is a Toeplitz matrix. You even wrote this matrix explicitly.

Therefore, I feel the most appropriate and exact solution is to "directly" maximize the conditional log likelihood (conditioned on $\phi$), equivalently minimize the negative log likelihood conditioned on $\phi$, and then maximize over $\phi$:

For each specific value of $\phi$, the log likelihood of $u$ conditioned on $\phi$ is a multivariate Gaussian of $u$ ($u_{\phi} = y - X\beta_{\phi}$), but it's necessary to keep the $det(V_{\phi})$ term, as explained below. For a specific value of $\phi$, i.e., conditioned on $\phi$, this is maximized by the Generalized Least Squares (GLS): $\beta_{\phi} = (X'V^{-1}_{\phi}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}_{\phi}y$.

But in order to maximize the overall unconditional (log) likelihood, it is necessary to compare likelihood values for different values of $\phi$, which requires to keep the $det(V_{\phi})$ term in the expression of the log likelihood.

Since the value of the unknown $\phi$ is in the bounded 1D range $-1 < \phi < 1$, it is a simple matter to maximize the unconditional likelihood over this range by a numerical 1D search (for example by a Fibonacci search for the maximum, etc.), or analytically by computing the $det(V_{\phi})$ as a function of $\phi$ and differentiating by $\phi$. (The analytical expression for $det(V_{\phi})$ as a function of $\phi$ can be obtained "easily", since $V$ has a very specific "easy" Toeplitz form.)

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Comment: You have to incorporate $\sigma^2$ (without which the (log-)likelihood can't be evaluated) as well. Maximizing the [profile (log-)likelihood](https://web.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/chapter3.pdf) of $\phi$ (treating both $\beta$ *and* $\sigma^2$, whose MLEs have closed-form expressions for a fixed $\phi$,  as nuisance parameters) in a one dimensional optimization would work.